# SharedPreferences and PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have done the examples for PreferenceFragments and SharedPreferences on the ANdroid developer website, however I'm running into an issue now.  I want to be able to access the preferences in my "Settings" screen from different Activities but I don't know what the name of the preference file generated by my preference fragment is.  Does anyone know anything about specifying the preference filename for a PreferenceFragment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Preferences should be saved to the default file.

To access, use [`PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (context);
```

`context` is any valid Context, including Activities.

From the documentation on [`PreferenceFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html):

> To retrieve an instance of SharedPreferences that the preference
>   hierarchy in this fragment will use, call
>   getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context) with a context in
>   the same package as this fragment.