# Shared preferences on fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to use shared preferences on Android inside a fragment with appcompat. It says me to "The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (PreferenciasFragment)" Here is my code:

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.commit();

        }
```

Comment: Try getActivity() instead of this.

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456496/sharedpreferences-and-preferencefragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the argument of `getDefaultSharedPreferences` should have `Context` type (or any of it's sub-classes). The problem is you are trying to pass `Fragment`, but it's not a sub-class of `Context`. Instead, you can pass hosting `Activity`, which is sub-class of `Context` like following:

```
Preferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```